# Can I use a valid Chinese visa in my expired UK passport if I have renewed my passport?

Tags: visas, paperwork, china

I have a 2-year multiple-entry Chinese visa that is still valid in my now expired UK passport. I now have a new passport, and need to know if I need to get a new visa or I can use the old one. I see conflicting information online.

From http://www.chinese-embassy.org.uk/eng/visa/qzxz/t1021775.htm

> 16. I have a new passport now but the Chinese visa on my old one is still valid. Can I go to China with both of these passports without applying for a new visa?
>
> Answer: You don't have to bring two passports. If your old passport has expired or its validity period is less than six months, then you need to apply for a new visa for your new passport.

But from http://www.china-embassy.org/eng/visas/faq/

> I get a new passport, but I have a valid Chinese visa in my old passport. Can I travel with both passports to China without applying for a new visa?
>
> Yes, you may travel with both passports provided that your visa is still valid and the personal details including your name, sex, date of birth and nationality on both passports are exactly the same.

Has anyone tried this recently? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

As stated in Timatic, the database used by airport check-in staff:

> Valid visas or resident permits in expired passports are
>     accepted if holding a new valid passport of the same
>     nationality. The personal information on both passports must
>     be the same.

So if the quote matches your circumstances, you're all good.

Present your valid passport at the main ID page, and the expired one at the visa page (if you're a resident, the page with the residence permit)